# XSL BI Publisher For-Each Loop print blank lines

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, rtf, bi-publisher

I have a for-each loop within my BI Publisher RTF template for repeating groups in the XML Output. When no data exists, I still need the for-each loop to output a blank table row. Kind of like an exception for the for-each loop. Is it possible?

XML Output:

```
<LIST_G_BOX_18_TO_20> 
 <G_BOX_18_TO_20>
  <SD_CODE></SD_CODE>
  <ASSIGNMENT_ACTION_ID5>2090950796</ASSIGNMENT_ACTION_ID5>
  <PAYROLL_ACTION_ID5>30381586</PAYROLL_ACTION_ID5>
  <TAX_UNIT_ID4>120</TAX_UNIT_ID4>
  <LOCALITY_NAME1>Euclid(OH)</LOCALITY_NAME1>
  <STATE_ABBREV>OH</STATE_ABBREV>
  <W2_LOCAL_WAGES>34.43</W2_LOCAL_WAGES>
  <W2_LOCAL_INCOME_TAX>.98</W2_LOCAL_INCOME_TAX>
 </G_BOX_18_TO_20>
<LIST_G_BOX_18_TO_20>
```

FOR-EACH LOOP

```
<?for-each:G_BOX_18_TO_20[W2_LOCAL_WAGES>0]?>
   <?if:position()!=1?><?STATE_ABBREV?>
  <?W2_LOCAL_WAGES?>
  <?W2_LOCAL_INCOME_TAX?>
  <?    xdofx:substr(LOCALITY_NAME1,1,decode(instr(LOCALITY_NAME1,'(',1),'0',length(LOCALITY_NAME1)+1,instr(LOCALITY_NAME1, '(', 1)) - 1)?>
 <?end if?>
 <?end for-each?>
```

Example of XML output when no data exists for element - G_BOX_18_TO_20:

```
<LIST_G_BOX_18_TO_20>
</LIST_G_BOX_18_TO_20>
```

Comment: The answer is yes! But to give a specific answer, can you show a sample of your input XML (with groups), and your current XSLT, along with the output you expect when there is no data. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your XML (and XSLT) as code is hard to read in comments. Thank you!

Comment: I've added the XML output and the for-each loop code

Comment: Can you give an example of a record where no data exists?

Comment: <LIST_G_BOX_18_TO_20>
</LIST_G_BOX_18_TO_20>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Add a second row to your table before the one you have in the loop. Apply one of these conditions to that new row so that it appears when the condition is met.

Condition A: Check if there's no records in the LIST element

```
<?if:LIST_G_BOX_18_TO_20 and LIST_G_BOX_18_TO_20="?><?end if?>
```

Condition B: Check if a LIST ITEM element doesn't exist

```
<?if:not(G_BOX_18_TO_20)?><?end if?>
```

**Option 2**

This applied prior to knowing some additional details, so it may be helpful for others to know. Take the condition out of the for-each, and make it an if statement on all the fields you don't want to appear when the condition is not met.

```
<?for-each:G_BOX_18_TO_20?>
   <?if:position()!=1?><?STATE_ABBREV?>
  <?if:W2_LOCAL_WAGES>0?><?W2_LOCAL_WAGES?><?end if?>
  <?if:W2_LOCAL_WAGES>0?><?W2_LOCAL_INCOME_TAX?><?end if?>
  <?if:W2_LOCAL_WAGES>0?><?xdofx:substr(LOCALITY_NAME1,1,decode(instr(LOCALITY_NAME1,'(',1),'0',length(LOCALITY_NAME1)+1,instr(LOCALITY_NAME1, '(', 1)) - 1)?><?end if?>
 <?end if?>
<?end for-each?>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working. I added a sample output where there's no data/elements for G_BOX_18_TO_20

Comment: Updated after your update.  Knowing about the list element was crucial.  I updated your original question to include that.

Comment: The additional row certainly seems to be working. Here's my modified IF condition: <?if:count(G_BOX_18_TO_20[W2_LOCAL_WAGES>0]) = 1 or count(G_BOX_18_TO_20[W2_LOCAL_WAGES>0]) = 0?><?end if?>. Make sure your IF and End If are not in the same cell of the table row. I needed this empty row to print when there's no data for G_BOX_18_TO_20 and also if there exists exactly one instance of G_BOX_18_TO_20[W2_LOCAL_WAGES>0] since that one would need printed in the row above. I'm using [W2_LOCAL_WAGES>0] so as to disregard groups where W2_LOCAL_WAGES = 0.

Comment: You can also rank your for-each loop results using position(). Example: <?if:position()=1?> Do Something <?end if?>